# Insert additional code in loaded json data

Tags: php, json

Hi,

I am loading some data in json but I need to insert some additional data based on the data that is loaded. This is an example of the data as it is loaded

```
{"markup":"<li id=\"com1\">some content</li><li id=\"com2\">some more content</li>"}
```

and this is the expected final result:

```
<li id="com1">some content <a href="delete=com1">DELETE</a></li>
<li id="com2">some content <a href="delete=com2">DELETE</a></li>
```

as you may see, I'm adding a delete link which has an URL that contains the ID of the element so I need a code to first find that ID and then add it into the right place for each element.

This is my php code:

```
$json = file_get_contents("data.txt");
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    echo $val;
    }
```

whats the best and simplest way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: The best way to do this is to parse the HTML using an HTML parsing library, like a DOM, and then insert the `<a>` elements into the DOM after the `text` element. Then output it back as text and assign it back to JSON.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate a little more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's php module for [parsing html](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) content. This might not be the answer you looking for. But this will give you some idea.

```
$str = file_get_contents("data.txt");
$data = json_decode($str,true);
$html = $data["markup"];
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$lis = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
foreach ($lis as $li) {
    $a = $dom->createElement('a','DELETE');
    $a->setAttribute('href','delete='.$li->getAttribute('id'));
    $li->appendChild($a);
}
$final = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $final;
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer.Just one question. Although the output seems to be right Im getting several warnings like this: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID com already defined in Entity, line: 36 in file.php on line 6

Comment: In HTML you cannot use same id twice. Id use for identify that element. So check your txt file.

Comment: I know, but I have no duplicate IDs in my html thats why I dont understand why this warning.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the error in the markup. Is there any way to get rid of the warnings? I mean, like preventing them to be output.

Comment: $dom->loadHTML($html,LIBXML_NOWARNING);

Comment: Didn't tried last method. But I think this will work. libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thank you. By the way, please check back on me later, I will be posting new questions related to this matter and I think you can help me out a lot.